# min-width: 960px with centered layout and additional 'wings'

Tags: html, css

The goal is to have `min-width: 960px;` with centered layout and additional 'wings' for bigger screen.

See the current implementation using negative margins: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8313423/wings.html

The problem is that when the window size is 960px or smaller, there is a horizontal scroll that allows to scroll till the end of yellow div(but should be just till the end of the text). In this implementation horizontal scroll appears when a viewpoint reaches a yellow div, but it should only show up when it reaches the text. It seems to me that the negative right-margin is ignored.

Any ideas how to fix horizontal scroll behaviour?

Comment: Link now shows the working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 70px of padding on each side and padding is included in the box size. Instead of being 960px wide, it's 1100px (960 + 70 + 70 = 1100) wide. Even though you have negative margins, the box size is unaffected by those so you will get a horizontal scroll on any width less than 1100px.

Comment: Tx! Is there a way to make scroll appear on width only less than 960px and still have these 'wings'?

Comment: The scroll bar is going to appear based on the size of the container. If you don't plan to have any content and they are purely aesthetic, you can do give it the same look with a background on the body tag instead of the container itself.

Comment: Tx Brent. I've solved that with another wrapper, as I need a content inside there.